# ionic 5 probleme when i run ionic cordova build android

Tags: android, build, ionic5

1. I face probleme with ionic 5 build this is my package.json

the version is ionic 5 and angular 11

i tried to open it with android studio but it still the same probleme

I tried to change some version but still the same probleme

```
    {
  "name": "migrationto5",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ionic serve --port=8104",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/branch-io": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/dialogs": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.40",
    "cordova": "^11.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ionic-rating": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.24",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-ionic-image-viewer": "^0.7.4",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "socket.io": "3.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "update": "^0.7.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "branch-cordova-sdk": "^4.2.4",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.2.5",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.10.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^13.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.3",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.3.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "branch-cordova-sdk": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION": "27.+",
        "FCM_VERSION": "17.0.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media": {
        "KEEP_AVAUDIOSESSION_ALWAYS_ACTIVE": "NO"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-background-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
        "ANDROIDBLACKLISTSECURESOCKETPROTOCOLS": "SSLv3,TLSv1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROIDX_CORE_VERSION": "1.6.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly.",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
        "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "ANDROID_ICON_ACCENT": "#FF00FFFF",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_MONITORING": "false",
        "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_TAGMANAGER_VERSION": "17.0.0",
        "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_AUTH_VERSION": "19.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "19.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "22.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CONFIG_VERSION": "21.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_VERSION": "20.0.2",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "21.0.1",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_INAPPMESSAGING_VERSION": "20.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_FIRESTORE_VERSION": "23.0.2",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_FUNCTIONS_VERSION": "20.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_IID_VERSION": "21.1.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_INSTALLATIONS_VERSION": "17.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_VERSION": "18.1.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_NDK_VERSION": "18.1.0",
        "ANDROID_GSON_VERSION": "2.8.7",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION": "1.4.0"
      },
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
      "call-number": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

2.and this is the problem it always say that i have probleme with deprecated versio
what to do i really need this:

```
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been
 annotated with @OutputDirectory.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR1' without corresponding getter has been
 annotated with @Input.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR1'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR1'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR2' without corresponding getter has been
 annotated with @Input.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR2'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR2'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'quickstartFile' without corresponding getter has been
annotated with @InputFile, @Optional.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'quickstartFile'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'quickstartFile'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'searchedLocation' without corresponding getter has bee
n annotated with @Input.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'searchedLocation'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'searchedLocation'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 38s
22 actionable tasks: 22 executed
Command failed with exit code 1: E:\Firas\ionic\OAT\onatrouveIo\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b E:\Firas\ionic\OAT\onatrouveIo\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: any response please

Comment: Try to clarify your title that will help to have people that can help you